# PFFacebookUtils initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions freezes app (semaphore wait trap)

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, parse-platform

On the next launch after logging using FB, app freezes on `initializeFacebookWithApplicationLaunchOptions`.
Heard it was a problem before Parse v1.7.2, but I'm using latest SDKs:

```
Installing Bolts (1.2.2)
Installing FBSDKCoreKit (4.6.0)
Installing FBSDKLoginKit (4.6.0)
Installing FBSDKShareKit (4.6.0)
Installing Parse (1.8.5)
Installing ParseFacebookUtilsV4 (1.8.5)
```

(xcode 7.0, ios 9.0)

Anyone knows what's the problem?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a bug due to FBSDK was trying to post a notification on the main thread and was blocking it. Should be fixed in parse ios sdk 1.8.6.